# Select multiple cells in same column using UltraWinGrid

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

In the grid I have to select multiple cells in same column only. Should not allow user to select the cells from difference columns.

I have tried below code.

```
  Private Sub grdTransactions_InitializeLayout(ByVal sender As Object, _ 
    ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs) _ 
    Handles grdTransactions.InitializeLayout
         e.Layout.Override.CellClickAction = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellClickAction.CellSelect
  End Sub

  Private Sub grdTransactions_AfterSelectChange(sender As Object, _ 
     e As AfterSelectChangeEventArgs) Handles grdTransactions.AfterSelectChange

        Me.grdTransactions.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectTypeCell = UltraWinGrid.SelectType.Single
        Me.grdTransactions.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectTypeCol = UltraWinGrid.SelectType.Single

        Me.grdTransactions.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Override.SelectTypeCell = UltraWinGrid.SelectType.Extended
        Me.grdTransactions.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Override.SelectTypeCol = UltraWinGrid.SelectType.Single

       Me.grdTransactions.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Override.MultiCellSelectionMode = MultiCellSelectionMode.Default

      Me.grdTransactions.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Override.MaxSelectedCells = 100

  End Sub
```

The above code allow select cell from difference column. Tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one possible approach to solve this task, could be if you are using ultraGrid1_BeforeSelectChange() event. For example:

```
 private void ultraGrid1_BeforeSelectChange(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.BeforeSelectChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewSelections.Cells.OfType<UltraGridCell>().First().Column.Key != e.NewSelections.Cells.OfType<UltraGridCell>().Last().Column.Key)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```